# Select only rows where the last date is present

Tags: r

Let's say that I have the following data.

```
df = data.frame(name = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
                date = c("2011-01-01","2011-03-01","2011-05-01",
                         "2011-01-01","2011-05-01","2011-06-01",
                         "2011-07-01"))
df
```

I know the last date in the data set and only want to pick those names where data is available for the last date. So in the above example, the last date is only available for name B. Thus, I want to select only the rows for name B.

I can do simple hacks like this to get the desired result.

```
last_date = "2011-07-01"

#unique(df$name[df$date %in% last_date])
df[df$name %in% unique(df$name[df$date %in% last_date]),]
```

However, I was wondering if there was a dplyr/tidyverse or data.table solution for this task.

Comment: How do you "know" the `last_date` for the groups? What is the one for group A ? How did you find out "2011-07-01" as `last_date` for group B ?

Comment: Because last data is a parameter in the script that specifies the last date that the "name" could have been employed there. So if the last date is not there for that name, they were either fired or quit earlier.

Comment: So is "2011-07-01" a fixed `last_date` for all the groups?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this, with `dplyr` we can filter only those groups which have the `last_date`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(last_date %in% date)

#  name  date      
#  <fct> <fct>     
#1 B     2011-01-01
#2 B     2011-05-01
#3 B     2011-06-01
#4 B     2011-07-01
```

---

Or similarly in base R :

```
df[ave(df$date, df$name, FUN = function(x) last_date %in% x) == TRUE,]
```

---

Also, we can get all the `name` where you find `last_date` and filter those `name`s from the original dataframe.

```
df[with(df, name %in% name[date %in% last_date]), ]
```